# go2streetview error

Tags: qgis-plugins, google-street-view

I believe I have done something wrong on my PC - be it deleting the file or putting it in another folder, because since the middle of last week I have been trying to use the go2streetview plugin on the GIS and: it opens, I click on the map location I want to see, but the screen stays white. I will send a print for you to view, it is attached to this message.

I've already reinstalled the go2streetview plugin, uninstalled it and installed it again, downloaded other versions of QGIS, checked if everything was ok with the API key and apparently everything is ok and NOTHING, didn't work.

What is wrong?